# Do while loop not working? (Cannot find variable)

Tags: java

I am having trouble with my do while loop not finding my variable to test if the condition is true or not. Here is my code:

```
import java.util.Scanner;
public class Loops
{
  public static void main(String[] args){
   System.out.println("Programmer: Jarred Sylvester");
   System.out.println("Course:     COSC 111, Winter 2016");
   System.out.println("Lab#:        5");
   System.out.println("Due date:    Feb. 18, 2016");

   Scanner prompt = new Scanner(System.in);

   do{ 
   System.out.print("\nEnter a whole number: ");

   int num = prompt.nextInt();

   if(num % 2 == 0){
       System.out.println(num + " is even");
    }
   else{
       System.out.println(num + " is odd");

    }

    System.out.println("\nNumbers from 1 through " +num+ " are:");
    for(int counter = 1; counter <= num; counter++){
        System.out.print(counter + "    ");
    }

    int counter = 1;
    System.out.println("\n\nSquare of odd numbers from 1 through " + num + " are:");
    while(counter <= num){
        if(counter % 2 ==1){

        System.out.print((counter * counter)+ "     ");

        }
        counter++;
    }

    counter = 1;int sum =0;
    System.out.println("\n\nSum of even numbers from 1 through " +num+ " is:");
    while(counter <= num){

        if(counter % 2 == 0){
             sum+=counter;


        }

        counter++;
    }
     System.out.print(sum);


    System.out.println("\n\nNumbers from 1 through "+num+"(5 numbers per line):");
    for(int count = 1; count <= num; count++){
        System.out.print(count + "      ");

        if(count % 5 == 0){
            System.out.print("\n");

        }


    }

    System.out.println("\n\nDo it again, yes(or no)?");

  String play = prompt.next();
}while(play.equalsIgnoreCase("yes"));
}
```

}

The variable "play" at the end isn't being tested. Am I out of scope or something? I've looked everywhere for an answer but cannot seem to find a solution to my error. Thank you.

Comment: Please read "[How to create a Minimal, Complete, and Verifiable example](http://stackoverflow.com/help/mcve)", taking note of the *Minimal* part of it. And fix your indentations so the code becomes readable, to yourself and others.

Answer (score 4, accepted):

`play` must be declared before the do-while loop in order to be in scope of the `while` condition.

```
String play = "";
do {
    ...
    play = prompt.next();
} while(play.equalsIgnoreCase("yes"));
```

Answer (score 0):

You are out of scope because you are using a `do{} while()` loop. When java reaches the `do` statement, it skips down to your `while` statement to make sure it returns true. It doesn't even see the code in the middle until after that.

It's much easier to see the correct scope of a variable if you use a `while(condition){body}` statement since the variable is at the top, where we naturally expect the code that is executed first to be.

So I would use a while loop as explained above, and you will have to declare the `play` variable before that line. Hope that works :)

Answer (score 0):

Instead of declaring the `play` as a local variable declare it as a class level variable.

```
String play;
do {
    ...
    play = prompt.next();
} while(play.equalsIgnoreCase("yes"));
```

Comment: While you are correct. The answer that already said this was posted 16 minutes before yours...

Comment: While checking the code none of us posted. Later I realized.